# Last activity for all users on ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, asmack

We have ejabberd installed on our server.

I am using asmack 4.0.7 to interact with the ejabberd server.

I wish to know last activity (XEP-0012) of all the users.

I have 10 user accounts on our server. viz john@myserver.in, mike@myserver.in, jerry@myserver.in etc.

The behaviour of ejabberd is that to find last activity of a user, that user has to log in. I mean to check last activity of john@myserver.in, he will have to log in.

If i log in as john@myserver.in, then i successfully get last activity for john@myserver.in. With john logged in, if i retrieve last activities for mike@myserver.in, jerry@myserver.in or any other user, i get *service-unavailable* response for ejabberd server.

`<iq from='mike@myserver.in/Smack' to='john@myserver.in/Smack' type='error' id='uHn-5'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/><error code='503' type='cancel'>
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error></iq>`

My requirement is that to retrieve last activity without making logins for all users.

Is that possible ?

Please let me know if any other information is required for this query.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want last activity of all users, this is probably for backend tasks. You should not do that using the XMPP client protocol, but with backend module (ejabberd plugin or read from last database).

Comment: Mickaël, thanks for your valuable feedback.

On similar lines,
I would like to know, if the answer is same if i change the query from last activity (XEP-0012) to Offline message storage (XEP-0160) of all the users.

I wish to know Offline message storage (XEP-0160) of all the users.
The behaviour of ejabberd is that to know Offline message of a user, that user has to log in. I mean to check Offline message for john@myserver.in, he will have to log in.
My requirement is that to retrieve offline messages without making logins for all users.

Comment: Yes, same comment XEP-0160 define client behaviour not back-end processing. No "client" will retrieve all offline message of every users. You need to design your solution totally differently.

Comment: Mickael iam always getting last seen as 9223372036854775807 Here is my code please help me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312742/ios-xmpp-get-last-seen-of-a-user

Comment: @MaheshNarla Have you found solution for this i am also getting 9223372036854775807